# Reading data from a Tenma 72-7732 multimeter using PyUSB

Tags: python, usb, device, libusb, pyusb

I'm trying to read voltages from a Tenma 72-7732 multimeter with a HID USB connection using PyUSB and libusb.  This is my code so far:

```
def main():
    import usb.core
    import usb.util
    import usb.backend
    import sys

    #find device

    dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1a86, idProduct=0xe008)

    # did you find it?
    if dev is None:
        raise ValueError('Device not found')
    else:
        print "Device found"


    dev.set_configuration()


    endpoint = dev[0][(0,0)][0]

    data = dev.read(endpoint.bEndpointAddress, endpoint.wMaxPacketSize, 0, 100000)

    print data

main()
```

This finds the device, but when it tries to read the data, it gives a timeout error.  The multimeter has very bad documentation and support, so I can't go there for help.  How can I read the device successfully?

Comment: Usually after you have set the configuration for a USB device you have to bind all pipes. Then they are ready for read / write access.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know how to do that in PyUSB?

Comment: Actually not, I'm sorry! But have you considered this [documentation of PyUSB](http://pyusb.sourceforge.net/docs/1.0/tutorial.html)? You could try to get the descriptor (like in the example) first. Consider tools like USBlyzer as well, like that you may find issues quite easily.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the documentation but it doesn't help very much.  Adding the descriptor part doesn't change anything; I can easily see descriptors like dev.bLength, but it doesn't help with reading data. Thanks for the advice about USBlyzer; I'll try it out.

Comment: USBlyzer solved the problem; thanks! It turns out I had to send an initialization code to the multimeter.

Comment: @Sophie could you please post your working code? I am having the same issue at the moment.

Comment: @Sophie If you have found a solution to your problem then please take some time to post it here and accept it as an answer. This will be a great convenience for other users.

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple IR to RS232 adapter which consists of an IR detector strapped Anode to pin 4 and cathode to pin 2 (RX data). When hooked up to my PC with a simple terminal set to 2400 Baud, 7 Data 1 Stop, No parity, No handshake it produces the following string

013651211

which repeats about every 400 ms. The first 5 digits are as read on the meter, digit 6 is decimal point location, digit 8 is function position

VDC = 1 AmpDC = 9

Last digit seems to be auto/manual mixed with sign; the rest I don't need (yet).